# Issue when calling from Fiori Launchpad a flavor based on main menu

Tags: sap-fiori

Experimenting with Fiori Lauchpad and have already deployed a few tiles based on Personas flavors, most of them using a generic invocation (calling transaction /personas/launch and passing as parameter the flavor ID), all of them work.

Just tried to add another tile, passing as parameter a flavor based on the SAP main menu (SMEN). As soon as I click the tile, I get the message "Transaction SMEN is locked", something of course that does not apply, since I can use the flavor normally and it's (apparently) unlocked when viewing via SM01. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Answer below

"Check whether the following KBA applies to your case:

2786421 - Fiori Launchpad Tile to launch Backend transaction SMEN no longer works"

Personas/health reports all green but seems that this is not classified as a personas issue